# Exact floating point multiplication

Tags: floating-point

I want to multiply a*b using floating point numbers.

What is the condition on b such that the multiplication is exact for all a? (You may assume that both a and b are not excessively small/large)

For example, small powers of two work will work. What other numbers have this property?

Comment: Generally, multiplying by positive and negative powers of two or positive/negative zero will not produce rounding errors.

Comment: @chtz That's what I already say in the questions. I'd like to know if these are the only numbers with this property.

Comment: No, everything else will add at least one bit to the significant, which may or may not be exactly representable.

Comment: Aside from powers of two, the only other values of b that will not cause inexactness for any a are zeroes, infinities, and NaNs.

Comment: @hanno You didn't mention a context where these exact multiplications are needed. Maybe you can restrict `a`? In general, the product will be exact if it can be represented with at most 24 bits for IEEE-754 `binary32` (single precision), at most 53 bits for IEEE-754 `binary64` (double precision). There are contexts where this is exploited by guaranteeing a sufficient number of trailing zero bits in the signficands of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to multiply `a*b` using floating point numbers.

**For *binary* floating point numbers**

> What is the condition on `b` such that the multiplication is exact for **all** `a`?
> (You may assume that both `a` and `b` are not excessively small/large)

> ... small powers of two work will work. What other numbers have this property?

Aside from powers of two, the only other values of `b` that will not cause inexactness for any `a` are zeroes, infinities, and NaNs.
[@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032630/exact-floating-point-multiplication#comment135801353_77032630)

... everything else will add at least one bit to the significant, which may or may not be exactly representable.
[@chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032630/exact-floating-point-multiplication/77078454#comment135800854_77032630)

**For *decimal* floating point numbers**

Then it is likewise for *powers of 10*.